# Connecting new 2014 Mac Mini and 2009 Mac Book Pro thru one VGA display

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-mini, vga

Is it possible to connect my mac Book Pro running 10.8.5 and a new Mac Mini running 10.9.2 Mavericks into one Apple VGA display, so as to be able to switch between desktops?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like a KVM switch? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

Answer (score 1):

Both MacBook Pro and the Mac Mini have Mini-DisplayPort on them. 
You can connect the Mini-DisplayPort to an Minii-DisplayPort-to-VGA converter and then, 
connect VGA cable on it to a two-port VGA DDM KVM switch, such as ConnectPRO's UR-12+.

I had been using this configuration for years without problem.